# Parenthetical phrases or not?

Tags: phrases, commas

Regarding this (original) sentence:

> Off of the great room, to the left of the fireplace, was a spiral staircase leading up to the second floor, where the bedrooms were, and down to the basement, where the spiders were.

You could easily, lucidly write this:

> Off of the great room was a spiral staircase leading up to the second floor and down to the basement.

Which means that the removed parts are "not necessary," and in need of commas, but this seems to work just fine:

> Off of the great room to the left of the fireplace was a spiral staircase leading up to the second floor where the bedrooms were and down to the basement where the spiders were.

Is it just a matter of style? Or is one "wrong," "improper," or "frowned upon?"

Comment: Most words in most sentences can be omitted. It is not the job of a comma to mark all things that can be left out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the role of the comma (and other punctuation) is to increase readability by breaking a sentence into chunks which the reader can parse and comprehend one at a time.  They often correspond to small pauses in natural speech which fulfil the same purpose: each pause is telling the listener "Ok, store that little chunk of meaning, here comes the next one".

The comma-free version at the end of your question illustrates this: it is **much harder to comprehend**.  It feels rushed, and is liable to confuse the reader, or at least force them to re-read it in order to comprehend it.

Ultimately, the purpose of language is communication, and so a sentence that communicates an idea more clearly than another can be said to be "better" than that other sentence.  The "rules of grammar" can be helpful in this regard, but they're not "king":  communication is king.